# How to do boxing in C++?

Tags: c++11

I have a following program, it fails to compile I believe this because it is trying to do begin(), end() on int i.e. primitive type. Perhaps, I need a object type. Am I correct here? How can I fix this , I want to use lambda here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    int N, i;
    cin >> N;

    int numArray[N]; // Define an array of four integers

    // Get inputs for the array elements
    for (i=0;i<N; i++) {
        cin >> numArray[i];
    }

    int sum = 0;
    // Write here the logic to add these integers:


    for_each(begin(numArray), end(numArray), [&](int n){ sum += n; });

    cout << sum << endl;  // Print the sum

    return 0;
}
```

compilation error-

```
 main.cpp:22: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int [N])'
         for_each(begin(numArray), end(numArray), [&](int n){ sum += n; });
                            ^
```

Comment: If compilation fails, *always* include the compiler output in the question.

Comment: `int numArray[N];` This is not legal C++. You are using a GCC language extension.

Comment: The question is how can I make it work with the extensions in mind?

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::begin(numArray)` and `std::end(numArray)`.

Comment: what's the reason why it works with begin() rather than .begin(). How will I know the mechanism behind?

Comment: @PrawnHongs: What do you mean by "*begin() rather than .begin()*"? `.` notation only works with objects of class types. `numArray` is an array, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

   std::vector<int>numArray;   // Define a vector of integers
        int i;
    // Get inputs for the array elements
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        int num = 0;
        cin>>num;
        cout<<"input number:"<<num<<endl;
        numArray.push_back(num);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    // Write the logic to add these integers here:

    for_each(numArray.begin(), numArray.end(), [&](int n){ 
        cout << "inside lambda function number:"<<n<<endl;
        sum += n; });

    cout << sum << endl;// Print the sum

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for_each(numArray, numArray + N, [&](int n){ 
        cout << "inside lambda function number:"<<n<<endl;
        sum += n; });
```

begin works on iterators and basically iterators are pointers. So, this will work.